# on iPads: UITableView's separator between header and cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad, header, separator

How can I remove the separator between header and cells in a UITableView?

you can see, it's this white fine line

[image]

At the beginning, I was developing in the xCode simulator using an iPhone 4S, and these lines didn't show.

I then run the app on an iPad Mini 3 device and these lines show up. Possibibly because of its higher definition.

any suggestion on how to remove this separator?

**UPDATE:**

It seems to only verify on iPads and iPadMinis. It doesn't even verify on iPhone 6S.

Comment: It's not clear if you're talking about the tableViewHeader or a section header, but I'd try setting your tableview's background color to the same as your cells, or your view's background color if your tableviews background color is clear.

Comment: I am talking about the header inside the section of a UITableView. I have tried to change the UITableView background, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: is the screen shot containing two table view cell? why not just make them into one cell so that it is easier to arrange

Comment: in iOS7 and up this is normal behaviour..... try changing your section height header in storyboard of your tableview in Size Inspector pane

Comment: What is the height of the contentView of your section header? What is the height of the section header? Seems like you're about a half point short.

Comment: You can also set the backgroundView of your sectionHeaderFooterView to be a view of the same color as your cells.

Comment: the height of the headers is defined programmatically in the UITableView class

Comment: @zp_x, the screenshot shows a section header and the first cell

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem and solved it by setting same color to header view while passing it to `viewForHeaderInSection` method. I was loading header view from storyboard, changing color in storyboard didn't solve my problem, but changing color programatically while passing it to `viewForHeaderInSection` is solved the problem.
 Here is the snippet.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    // You can load 'headerView' from xib or storyboard
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 50))
    headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 248, g: 248, b: 248, a: 0.94)
    return headerView
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 50
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the storyboard like so:
[image: Seperator style none]

Or in your viewController

Swift:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = .None
```

Objc:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = .None;
```

Comment: @DanieleB reload the table?

Comment: it is set to None in the Interface Builder

Comment: This solution is to remove the separator between tableview cells, not the separator between header and first cell.